# Limit the allowed browsers for Android inside react-native-app-auth

Tags: react-native, openid-connect

I'm using `react-native-app-auth` to login in our application and I noticed it crashes if I use some browsers. `react-native-app-auth` should allow to whitelist some browsers through the `androidAllowCustomBrowsers` property but I can't find what values should be listed there. Does anybody have a clue what to put inside that array? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may find in source code of `react-native-app-auth`, options are listed in [**index.d.ts**](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/f8c9162d5b8654dda95ca63a67f608c294908fec/index.d.ts#L83).

```
androidAllowCustomBrowsers?: ('chrome' | 'chromeCustomTab' | 'firefox' | 'firefoxCustomTab' | 'samsung' | 'samsungCustomTab')[]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking in the lastest release `index.d.ts` file and there the option doesn't even exist.

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like it works. I've set it to `chromeCustomTab` and still my window is opened with my OS default: Brave.

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: Tried with both 6.4.3 and 7.0.0 RC1

Comment: Since the feature is released in latest pre-release version 7.0.0-rc1, maybe there is bug with that. It is better to ask in its [github](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues).